# Для чего нужен формат "reference|color"?

Tags: android

У атрибутов есть формат `reference`. Он может хранить любые ссылки по типу `@layout/...`, `@color/...` и так далее. Также есть формат `color`. Сначала я думал, что он может хранить только значения по типу `#F44336`. Но как оказалось атрибуты с данным форматом спокойно могут ссылаться на любые ссылки также как и атрибуты с форматом `reference`.

Иногда я вижу атрибуты, чей формат определен следующим образом:

```
<attr format="color|reference" name="actionMenuTextColor"/>
```

**Вопрос:** в чем смысл формата `color|reference` если по сути он делает тоже самое что и `color` (может ссылаться на ссылки + хранить такие значение как `#F44336`) ?

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае reference для возможности подставлять [Color state list resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource), а иногда [Drawable resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource) (например `android:background`), зависит на самом деле, как это обрабатывается в коде. Если вы подставите что-то неподходящее, то будет краш

Comment: и первый и второй без проблем работают с `color`

Comment: @VanechikSpace пример такого атрибута можно?

Comment: я просто сделал свой атрибут с `color` форматом и попробовал использовать его в своей теме ссылаясь сначала на `@drawable`, а потом на [Color state list resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource). попробовал сбилдить и все отлично сбилдилось

Comment: @VanechikSpace то, что сбилдилось, не значит, что будет работать как надо, я же написал, что будет краш, те runtime error, либо какое-то другое кривое поведение

Comment: мой атрибут - `<attr name="qwer2" format="color"/>` сначала в теме присвоил ему `@drawable`, а затем в `ImageButton` написал `android:src="?qwer2"`. Запустил всё отлично работает. Потом присвоил атрибуту `@color/cool` (cool - название папки, т.е. использовал  Color state list resource), а в обычном `Button` написал `android:textColor="?qwer2"`. Запустил всё отлично работает.